# KineticJS Mouseover not working

Tags: kineticjs

I've tried everything to get this to work ending with hard coding the numbers in, but when I mouseover the stage nothing happens at all.  The mouseover (or mousemove) will only activate when I'm actually over the image itself.  Can anyone tell me how to make an image move left or right whenever I move my mouse over the stage?

`stage.on('mouseover', function(){
                var mousePos = stage.getUserPosition();
                if (mousePos.x >= 289)
                {
                rect.move(5, 0);
                }
                else
                {
                rect.move(-5,0);
                }
                stage.add(layer);
          });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KineticJS Moverover working when we add the Rectangle(Transparent) before the image. See the below code, its working.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>  
  <head>    
    <style>      
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      canvas {
        border: 1px solid #9C9898;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.0.0.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
          container: "container",
          width: 578,
          height: 200
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function() {
          var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
            x: 140,
            y: stage.getHeight() / 2 - 59,
            image: imageObj,
            width: 106,
            height: 118
          });         
          var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
              x: 0,
              y: 0,
              width: stage.getWidth(),
              height: stage.getHeight()
          });

          layer.add(rect);
          layer.add(yoda);
          stage.add(layer);

          stage.on('mousemove', function(){ 
            var mousePos = stage.getUserPosition(); 
            if (mousePos.x >= 289) 
            { 
              yoda.move(5, 0);
            } 
            else 
            { 
              yoda.move(-5, 0);
            } 
            layer.draw();
          });
        };
        imageObj.src = "http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/yoda.jpg";
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```